# How do I change the Target Framework on a Visual Studio Modeling Project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, uml

We recently migrated to .NET 4.5.2 and now our modeling project has warnings like this one:

> The primary reference "XXX" could not be resolved because it was built
>   against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" framework. This is a higher
>   version than the currently targeted framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5".

I can't figure out how to change the target framework for the modeling project. It doesn't have a normal project properties UI I can access. Nor does the .modelproj file have a TargetFrameworkVersion node I could hand-edit.

I would ignore the warnings, except layer diagram validation is broken (validation succeeds when it shouldn't), and layer diagram validation is our primary use of this project. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the various "packages" and then redragging your class files only your model space?

Comment: And it should go without saying, but I'm going to say it anyways: save your project before doing something drastic like deleting all the packages in your UML diagrams.

Comment: I just tried created a brand new solution with 3 brand new projects: LibA with a dependency on LibB and a new ModelingProject with a Layer Diagram showing the two libs - no arrow. When both libs were .NET 4.5, validation failed (correctly, since the diagram is missing that dependency arrow.) Then I changed both libs to .NET 4.5.2, cleaned and rebuilt. Now I get warnings and validation passes...

Comment: @JanaMandic Have you found a way to fix this? I am hitting the same problem, but it's saying `which was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" framework? This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1"` I tried manually adding a `TargetFramework` property to the modelling project, but doesn't help.

Comment: @IvanZlatev Sorry, I haven't actually... It's been on my back-burner to call Microsoft support about this, but I haven't gotten around to it yet. I'll answer this question when I get an answer from support.

Comment: @JanaMandic I've opened a connect issue here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1138085

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called Microsoft Technical Support. This is a bug in VS2012 but it has been fixed in VS2013. One more reason to upgrade to latest!

Comment: still happening to me, I'm in VS2013 ultimate update 4 with .net 4.6.00057 installed

Comment: This just started happening to me in VS2017 after updating to 15.8.1 (from 15.7.something - where it worked fine)